# SQL update with sub select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an update query and it did not work. I need to correct this query.

```
update table1 set testID =
     (select testID,
       REPLACE (REPLACE(testid, 'A', '1'), 'B', 2) testID
       FROM table1
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you don't need a subquery at all:

```
update table1
    set testID = REPLACE(REPLACE(testid, 'A', '1'), 'B', 2)
    where testID LIKE '%[AB]%';
```

The `where` clause just checks that the id is actually going to change.  No need to update the record if nothing changes.

Comment: I do have subquery like above.

Comment: Your subquery has 2 columns and you are setting one column at first thats completely wrong also the subquery will return whole data to set for a particular row at a time hence use the above Gordons answer i hope that clears out

Comment: Thank  you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would work!

```
update table1 set testID =
     (select 
       REPLACE (REPLACE(testid, 'A', '1'), 'B', 2) AS testID
       FROM table1 
       where condition1=column
    )
where condition2=column;
```

or

```
update table1 
set testID = REPLACE (REPLACE(testid, 'A', '1'), 'B', 2)
where condition1=column;
```